Get names of devices in network
I'm currently working with Flutter and would like to build an app that does a simple network scan and lists all devices.
So, i started with the lan_scanner and network_info_plus flutter plugin.
Unfortunately I only get the IP addresses but I need the device name.
My first thought was to use the device_info_plus plugin, but this only returns information about the device on which the app is running.
I could establish a socket connection to every active IP address that the lan_scanner returns in order to get the device name, but most devices run on very different ports that I was not able to find out beforehand.
Is it even possible to get this kind of information with Flutter?
I tried the example app from the lan_scanner plugin and a Stream Connection on active founded IP Adresses in the actual wifi network on Port 80. But the most devices in the wifi network has different ports then port 80. So i think this Idea is bad.

This question is similar to: Flutter/Dart: Scan local network to get IP and hostname of connected devices. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In this question the answer belongs to a solution on making a socket request only on port 22. But devices in a network has different ports.

With the lan_scanner i get only the ip addresses of active devices in the actual wifi network. I also need the device name.

Please have a look at the InternetAddress(socket.address.address).reverse() in the answer

Crazy. Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. Is it still possible to intercept the “unknown” devices somehow and then give them the name Generic? (InternetAddress(device.internetAddress.address).reverse().then((value) => ...);) Can i check the content of value?
